# Drinking vodka through a straw - stronger or not?

Tags: spirits

Question: If I drink my vodka through a straw will it have a stronger effect.  There is a question [here](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/4797/drinking-beer-with-a-straw) that sort of addresses my query, but does it apply to spirits as well?

Comment: The only mechanism I can see which would make this work is if you're by-passing having to taste the spirit and immediately consuming it, which would allow you to drink it faster.

Comment: Well my Wife drank threw a straw last night for no particular reason. And she was well drunk and I mean in all my years I have never seen her that drunk. She didn’t consume anymore than a normal night out. Had a good meal before we went out. So from a personal point YES! drinking via a straw does make you get drunk faster/worse.

Comment: No this is completely true from personal experience i am 23 and a straw does get u more drunk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some people have made the claim that drinking through a straw will get you more drunk than drinking without one. This seems to be a Myth.

> Many people have claimed that drinking alcohol through a straw gets you drunk faster than drinking it regularly.
>
> Proponents of the Straw theory have two primary claims.  First, when drinking through a straw, people usually drink faster than if they were drinking regularly. Because they are ingesting more alcohol in a shorter period of time, they will clearly get more drunk faster.  Secondly, a straw creates a vacuum, which eliminates oxygen. **The feeling of intoxication is created in part, because of the lack of oxygen entering us, so when we form a vacuum with a straw, we should naturally get more drunk.** Additionally, by creating a vacuum with the straw, the boiling point of alcohol falls, and alcohol vapors are created within the straw, then inhaled into the lungs. This gets the alcohol into the bloodstream much faster than normal ingestion via the stomach.
>
> **However, many opponents of the straw method say that although this science is true, the difference would be so negligible it wouldn't even be noticeable.**  [The New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/1991/07/30/science/q-a-666591.html) even went a step further in ts Q&A section, writing that "There is no evidence that people get drunk faster if they drink alcoholic beverages through a straw, according to the National Institute on Alcoholic Abuse."  And even the folks at Mythbusters weighed in on the topic, when it was posted in the community forums of their website, claiming that it was "Busted." - [Do you get Drunk Faster with a Straw?](http://www.personal.psu.edu/afr3/blogs/SIOW/2011/09/do-you-get-drunk-faster-with-a-straw-1.html)

Comment: Related: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/does-drinking-alcohol-through-a-straw-make-you-drunk-quicker